# jquery validation plugin for dynamic element ID

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I need to validate bunch of text boxes which has dynamic ID. The elements are available on document ready, not dynamically inserted.

```
<input type="text" class="y"/>
<input type="text" class="y"/>
<input type="text" class="y"/>
<input type="text" class="y"/>
<input type="text" class="y"/>
```

The rule is that one of the first two field is required. I'm lost how to validate without knowing ID of the element.

**EDIT:**  Input elements are generated by loop so I cant add class **required** for first two. I'm looking for a solution using jquery Validation plugin http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Comment: Always first 2 elements or requirement is changed?

Comment: What criteria do you choose which one needs to be validated?

Comment: don't input's have a `name` in order to submit?

Comment: Always first 2 to be validated. I skipped name and other attributes for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if($('input:text:eq(0)').val()=="" && $('input:text:eq(1)').val()==""){
 //show error
}
});
```

Comment: there is no `:second` selector use `:eq(index)` selector or `eq(index)` method

Comment: close...needs to be one or other is valid... so use `||` instead of `&&` in the `if` and `input` doesn't have `text()` method..use `val()`

Comment: @charlietfl:but he wants either one of them is mandatory...then im guessing that if both fields are empty,it should throw error?

Comment: oops..my bad..  you are right.. small hours of the morning here

Comment: OP says he's looking for solution using jQuery Validate plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Following uses filter to create collection of the 2 inputs that value is not empty..  Testing the length provides a validity test

```
var valid=$('input').slice(0,2).filter(function(){
   return $(this).val() !='';
}).length

if(valid){
  /* can submit*/
}
```

Solution for validation plugin:

```
 $('input:lt(2)').addClass('required');
```

NOTE: adjust selector to fit form better so it doesn't find every input in page, or inputs in form that are not part of the collection you want to validate. you could wrap these inputs in a fieldset and give fieldset an ID

Comment: OK...that's simple enough by adding class `required`. I updated answer. You can use classes with validation plugin, or write `rules` object.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if($('input:text:lt(2)').val()=="" ){
 //error 
}
});
```

Comment: won't quite work `val()` will only return value of first element

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you want is this:

```
function isValid(){
    var cont=0;
    $('input:text').each(function(i, obj) {
        if(i<2 && obj.value){
             cont++; 
        }
      });
    return cont==2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try This :

You can do it using [`:lt();`](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) like this:

```
$("form input:lt(2)");
```

This selects all elements that match at less-than the passed index, the first and second elements are index 0 and 1, and will match this selector :)